# How to load png project file into an image on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How to load png project file into an image on Windows Phone 8 or 8.1?

Comment: Do you mean how to add a .png file into Assets to use in the app?

Comment: and what u have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets have an `Image` in XAML file, like:

```
        <Image Name="img"/>
```

Now, Assign its `source` from Assets in code file like:

```
        img.Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/text1.png", UriKind.Relative) };
```

thats it.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri.

Comment: With replacement or relative URI with absolute one  
`Flag.Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Flags/" + Flags.list[flagIndex].filename + ".png", UriKind.Absolute) };`  
it worked like a charm.
Thank you very much for answering such primitive question.